# ICommand method execute parameter value

Tags: c#, parameters, execute, icommand

I try to understand the ICommand from wpf.

In my Event class I implement the ICommand and their methods.

one method is the Execute:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    //Do something
}
```

now is my question: what value contains the  parameter `parameter` from `Execute`?

Comment: Anything you need for your command to execute. If you don't need anything, it can be null. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.execute.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That value depends on the value you *pass* to the command.

like  a sniplet:

```
Command="{Binding CalculateCommand}" CommandParameter="LCM"/>
```

Look here: [Command Binding with Parameter Passing](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/command-binding-with-parameter-passing/) for more details.